# GoDaddy + WP, can't upload anything

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, godaddy

I'm on dedicated hosting with GoDaddy. WP installed, but can't upload anything. Getting the following error:

```
the error: Is its parent directory writable by the server?
```

The upload folder is already 777. I'm guessing it is an ownership issue. What is Apache's owner/group name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache's owner/group name can be a variety of things, depending on the distribution.  `www-data`, `apache`, `httpd`, even `nobody` gets a run sometimes.

And get rid of the 777 on that directory -- it's a menace.

Comment: I did 777 out of desperation. I've tried apache:apache. Will try owner/groups you suggested.

Comment: I tried all those. Nothing worked. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried actually looking at what Apache is currently running as on the server?